# Не работает соединение docker между машинами admin и updater

Tags: ubuntu, docker, tcp, docker-compose

Я пытаюсь настроить две машины так, чтобы на одной хранилась база данных, а другая получала обновления. Если запускать машину-обновление на ПК, то все работает (на ПК updater настроен точно также как и на машине) но как только я запускаю ее на второй машине :

```
{
    "level": "error",
    "error": "Get http://IP/client/config: dial tcp IP:80: i/o timeout",
    "time": "2019-12-06T09:16:15Z",
    "message": "failed to fetch config"
}
```

Вот настройки docker-compose на updater:

```
version: '3'
services:
  onlineconf-updater:
    build: .
    image: onlineconf-updater
    volumes:
      - ./data:/usr/local/etc/onlineconf
    environment:
      ONLINECONF_ADMIN_HOST: IP
      ONLINECONF_ADMIN_PORT: 80
      ONLINECONF_UPDATER_USER: gopher
      ONLINECONF_UPDATER_PASSWORD: gopher
    restart: always
```

ADMIN:

```
version: '3'
services:
  onlineconf-admin:
    build: .
    image: onlineconf-admin
    depends_on:
      - onlineconf-database
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:80"
    environment:
      ONLINECONF_DATABASE_HOST: onlineconf-database
      ONLINECONF_DATABASE_BASE: onlineconf
      ONLINECONF_DATABASE_USER: onlineconf
      ONLINECONF_DATABASE_PASSWORD: onlineconf
    restart: always
  onlineconf-database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./etc/charset.cnf:/etc/mysql/conf.d/charset.cnf
      - ./etc/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-schema.sql
      - ./etc/notification.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2-notification.sql
      - ./etc/auth.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/3-auth.sql
      - ./etc/example.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/4-example.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: onlineconf
      MYSQL_USER: onlineconf
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: onlineconf
volumes:
  data: {}
```

Comment: А можно код оформить как код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам необходимо сделать docker сеть, а затем присоединить свои контейнеры к этой сети:

```
docker network create localNet
docker network connect localNet admin
docker network connect localNet updater
```

Comment: а если у меня они на разных машинах, на какой эту сеть создавать? И добавляется папка целиком? То есть папка admin и папка updater?

Comment: Тогда указывай айпи машины + порт, который прокидывал из докера наружу.